# Force input widget creation in Shiny even if widget has not yet been displayed in browser

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny, one can use the following line to force displaying/refreshing an output even if not displayed within the ui:

```
outputOptions(output, "my_output", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

**Is there a similar way to "force" input widget creation?**

My context: I do have a button that pre-populate a textinput on another tab. Potentially, this textinput may not been generated yet if user didn't go to this specific tab. In such a case, the pre-population legitimely fails.

Good practice would probably be to use a reactiveValues, to feed it with the "pre-populate value" when clicking the button, and then to use this rv within the input widget creation. But I was wondering if a similar option as the above was available in Shiny.

Comment: I think you are much more likely to get a useful answer if you provide a reproducible example of the issue that you have.

Comment: `outputOptions` allowed me to solve a rendering problem when collapsing elements. Not what was intended with your question, but thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a simple, working example of the situation I think you are describing.
That is, you don’t need to do anything special.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("A", actionButton("populate", "Populate B things")),
    tabPanel("B", textInput("b_text", "Add some B text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$populate, {
    updateTextInput(session, "b_text", value = "Updated from tab A")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If the input you want to update is generated with `uiOutput()` then you can
use `outputOptions()` to force evaluation, like you already mentioned:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("A", actionButton("populate", "Populate B things")),
    tabPanel("B", uiOutput("b_panel"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$populate, {
    updateTextInput(session, "b_text", value = "Updated from tab A")
  })
  
  output$b_panel <- renderUI({
    textInput("b_text", "Add some B text")
  })
  
  outputOptions(output, "b_panel", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```